# Trouble running pig in both local or mapreduce mode

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I already have Hadoop 1.2 running on my Ubuntu VM which is running on Windows 7 machine. I recently installed Pig 0.12.0 on my same Ubuntu VM. I have downloaded the pig-0.12.0.tar.gz from the apache website. I have all the variables such as JAVA_HOME, HADOOP_HOME, PIG_HOME variables set correctly. When I try to start pig in local mode this is what I see:

```
chandeln@ubuntu:~$ pig -x local
pig: invalid option -- 'x'
usage: pig

chandeln@ubuntu:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java7  
chandeln@ubuntu:~$ echo $HADOOP_HOME
/usr/local/hadoop
chandeln@ubuntu:~$ echo $PIG_HOME
/usr/local/pig
chandeln@ubuntu:~$ which pig
/usr/games/pig

chandeln@ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java7/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/local/pig/bin
```

Since I am not a Unix expert I am not sure if this is the problem but the command `which pig` actually returns `/usr/games/pig` instead of `/usr/local/pig`. Is this the root cause of the problem?

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by changing the following lines in my .bashrc. This gave precedence to the `/usr/local/pig` directory instead of `/usr/games/pig`

```
BEFORE: export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PIG_HOME/bin
AFTER: export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PIG_HOME/bin:$PATH
```