# Apache Pig not working

Tags: apache-pig

I'm working on apache pig. I have installed Hadoop and it is running sucessfully. But when I enter the 'pig' command on the terminal , I do not get any output. I tried using 'pig -x local' but it gives the following error

```
pig: invalid option -- 'x'

usage: pig
```

I made the following changes in bashrc and profile -

bashrc-

```
export PIG_HOME=/usr/local/pig-0.12.1
export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin
export PIG_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/
```

profile-

```
export PIG_HOME=/usr/local/pig-0.12.1

export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

I cannot figure out why the output is not being displayed. Can you please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you echo $PATH and see if by any chance its referring to pig game? /usr/games/pig, if so pls change your export statement to load PIG_HOME prior to already set $PATH

Comment: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/usr/local/pig-0.12.1/bin:/usr/lib/hive-0.12.0/bin
This is what i m getting when i exec the echo $PATH still apache pig hangs up                                                                                                             I m using ubuntu 12.04 lts 32 bit

Comment: please try export PATH=$PIG_HOME/bin:$PATH instead of PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin, in current echo its visible /usr/games has high precedence over PIG_HOME

Comment: Also try to run it from PIG_HOME/bin directory itself once.

Comment: what is the output of the following two commands: cd $PIG_HOME and bin/pig -i.

Comment: Even I am facing the same problem. After pig command, I am not getting grunt> shell. The output of two commands - cd $PIG_HOME and bin/pig -i is: Apache Pig version 0.15.0 (r1682971) compiled Jun 01 2015, 11:43:55. What is the solution for this?

Comment: can you try pig –version just to check if the 'pig' command is working correctly.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619306/trouble-running-pig-in-both-local-or-mapreduce-mode

Answer (score 1):

just follow steps:

1. Open your .bashrc file using command `$ gedit ~/.bashrc`
   (this will open your .bashrc file in text editor)
2. copy below code and paste it in your .bashrc file

   export PIG_HOME=/usr/local/pig-0.16.0

   export PIG_CONF_DIR=$PIG_HOME/conf

   export PIG_CLASSPATH=$PIG_CONF_DIR

   export PATH=$PIG_HOME/bin:$PATH
3. then save the file (<kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>), then close the file and go to terminal.
   then type

   source ~/.bashrc
4. press enter button again type

   pig -version
5. you will see below

   Apache Pig version 0.16.0 (r1746530)

   compiled Jun 01 2016, 23:10:49

it means you are on right track.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if in `/usr/games` you have a pig file. If that's the case then you should run the following commands-

```
sudo apt-get remove bsdgames
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove bsdgames
sudo apt-get purge bsdgames
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove bsdgames
```

After this shut down the system and then after starting use pig -version command. I hope it helps!

Comment: Please don't provide link-only answers, put the most important bits to your post directly. This way, the answer won't get irrelevant if the link gets broken and also is more helpful (easier to use). You may see that your answer has already got a downvote, and this is probably the reason. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

check the  .bashrc file and see whether that very line is commented or not..and after that make sure hadoop  path--

"*export PIG_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/bin*"

"*export PIG_HOME=/usr/local/pig-0.12.1*"

is written correctly.
if not  try to reinstall/update the Pig

Answer (score 0):

If anyone facing issue with apache-pig setup

here is solution:

```
rock@rock-VirtualBox:~$ pig -version

pig: invalid option -- 'v'

usage: pig

rock@rock-VirtualBox:~$ pig -x local

pig: invalid option -- 'x'

usage: pig
```

If your facing same above issue, just follow steps:

```
rock@rock-VirtualBox:~$ gedit .bashrc
```

Change like or write else copy paste in gedit

PIG_HOME PATH:-

```
export PIG_HOME=/usr/local/Hadoop-env/pig-0.16.0

export PIG_CONF_DIR=$PIG_HOME/conf

export PIG_CLASSPATH=$PIG_CONF_DIR

export PATH=$PIG_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Press ctrl+s to save it, close gedit then go to command line/terminal

```
rock@rock-VirtualBox:~$ source .bashrc

rock@rock-VirtualBox:~$ pig -version

Apache Pig version 0.16.0 (r1746530) 

compiled Jun 01 2016, 23:10:49
```

---

issue is solved as per my case